# Ajax is updating all attributes on a cropped image, therefore reprocessing the image without the cropped dimensions

Tags: ajax, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, jcrop

I'm cropping images with carrierwave and Jcrop. The model that holds the image is called `Item` and the field that stores the image is called `cover`.

The cropping is working well. The problem is to do with an ajax action for voting for the item.

Each item has a field called `votes`. I have a button on top of the item that when clicked adds 1 to the `votes` value by increment. If I don't use the ajax action, it updates the record correctly, no harm done. However, if I use the ajax action it updates all of the fields in the Item record with new attributes, attributes that change the dimensions of the cropped image to almost zero, which then triggers the after_update callback that reprocesses the image.

The result is that I get an image that is 1px by 1px and completely white.

How can I change my ajax action to that this doesn't happen?

Thanks

```
  def vote
    item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    item.increment!(:votes)

    if request.xhr?
      render json: {votes: item.votes}
    else
      redirect_to users_url
    end
  end

jQuery ($) ->
  $('form.vote').submit (evt) ->
    evt.preventDefault()

    $form = $ @
    $form.find(':submit').prop 'disabled', true
    $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray(), type: 'json').done (data) ->
      $form.parent().find(".vote_count").text data.votes
```

And for reference the Item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :update_image_attributes
  before_update :reprocess_image, :if => :cropping?

  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :available, :cover, :privacy, :size, :title, :votes, :user_id, :description, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

  mount_uploader :cover, CoverUploader

  def cropping?
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
  end

  private

  def update_image_attributes
    if cover.present?
      self.content_type = cover.file.content_type
      self.file_size = cover.file.size
      self.width, self.height = `identify -format "%wx%h" #{cover.file.path}`.split(/x/)
    end
  end

  def reprocess_image
      cover.reprocess(crop_x, crop_y, crop_w, crop_h)
      cover.cache_stored_file!
  end

end
```

And Controller

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate

      def crop
        @item = Item.find(params[:image_id])
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @item.update_attributes(:crop_x => params[:crop_x],:crop_y => params[:crop_y],:crop_w => params[:crop_w],:crop_h => params[:crop_h])
            format.html { redirect_to items_url }
            format.js
          else
            redirect_to root_url
          end
        end
      end

      # GET /items
      # GET /items.json
      def index
        @items = Item.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @items }
        end
      end

      # GET /items/1
      # GET /items/1.json
      def show
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @item }
        end
      end

      # GET /items/new
      # GET /items/new.json
      def new
        @item = Item.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @item }
        end
      end

      # GET /items/1/edit
      def edit
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
      end

      # POST /items
      # POST /items.json
      def create
        @item = Item.create(params[:item])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @item.save
            format.html { redirect_to items_url }
            format.js
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PUT /items/1
      # PUT /items/1.json
      def update
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
            format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: "edit" }
            format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /items/1
      # DELETE /items/1.json
      def destroy
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        @item.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to items_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private

      def authenticate
        if current_user.nil?
          redirect_to root_path, :alert => "You must first log in to access this page"
        end
      end
    end
```

Update - log of the commit

```
Started POST "/vote" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-15 23:28:03 +0200
Processing by VotesController#vote as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uVxsVGsXImC2VPsavIjZfIUMnGmlyjYEmubI8oODgdk=", "item_id"=>"107", "user_id"=>"1"}
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
  Color Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "colors".* FROM "colors" 
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (9.2ms)  INSERT INTO "votes" ("created_at", "item_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 15 Aug 2012 21:28:03 UTC +00:00], ["item_id", 107], ["updated_at", Wed, 15 Aug 2012 21:28:03 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
   (3.1ms)  commit transaction
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 107]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE "items" SET "votes" = 1, "updated_at" = '2012-08-15 21:28:03.656131' WHERE "items"."id" = 107
   (23.2ms)  commit transaction
```

Comment: What does you log say about the params when you do ajax?

Comment: I updated it, the log doesn't say much.

Comment: BTW, you probably don't want to store crop_x, etc in the database.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right. I'll think of a solution!

Comment: You only need them when cropping, so they can be normal attributes (attr_accessor)

Comment: Thanks man! Really appreciate your help! I'll rewrite the process and see how it goes.

Comment: I changed the reprocess_image from a private method into a normal one and only called it in the cropping action, so now its not called every time I update it. I swear I tried that before but atleast now its working! Cheers Gleb!

Comment: :cropping? was always true because you stored the values in DB...

Comment: Yeah thats the problem using it as an after_update. It really should just be a method in an action called crop.